# Configure firewalld for OpenVPN (server-bridge) in Fedora 20

Tags: firewall, openvpn, network-interface, firewalld

I've installed an OpenVPN server on Fedora 20 (server-bridge), but I cannot get it to work. I'm almost sure that It's a firewall issue.

I'm trying to connect from an OSX client, but I can connect (just connect to VPN server, without access to anything) before the bridge is configured in server, however once I configure the bridge interface (using [this](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html#linuxscript) script), then I cannot connect anymore. I've configured it as server-bridge, following these HOW-TOs from [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Openvpn) and [OpenVPN Ethernet-Bridge](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html).

The firewall config is explained using iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

However, in Fedora 20, by default, It's installed firewalld, so, Can anyone tell me the equivalent commands using `firewall-cmd` ? I read the [firewalld guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD), but It's not clear to me how to achieve it (I'm a developer, no SysAdmin).

I know that I can install iptables, but I want it to work with firewalld.

Comment: I removed the fedora tags and created a `firewalld` tag.